# Python: Import all modules from package

Tags: python

There is a package. In the package's `__init__.py` there is `__all__` defined which contains name of every module in package. If I then use

```
from package import *
```

will it import every module of that package so I can reference them by name?

Is it possible in Python to import every package's module with `from x import *` statement?

Comment: yes it will work

Comment: Yes it would work but generally not suggested. refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad) for why

Answer (score 0):

Yes. But because of "namespace pollution" (not knowing which imported module you actually use because perhaps several of them have the same name), it is not recommended.